# Tочность числовых значений типа данных FLOAT

Tags: sql, oracle, float

Есть таблица с типом данных столбца `FLOAT`, как определено в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28285/sqlqr06.htm#CHDBBHHE).

Вставляю число с 52 двоичными знаками (не считая начальной 1, которая является неявной), но вижу, что для хранения без округления достаточно только 50 знаков.

Как такое может быть?

```sql
create table numeric_types2 (fl float(60));

insert into numeric_types2 SELECT BIN_TO_NUM (
    1,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,1                  ) FROM DUAL;
```

А результат приведения к различной точности:

```sql
select 
    to_char (cast(fl as float(49)), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') fl49,
    to_char (cast(fl as float(50)), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') fl50,
    to_char (cast(fl as float(51)), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') fl51
from numeric_types2;
```

Вывод:

```
FL49               FL50               FL51              
------------------ ------------------ ------------------
    10000000000004     10000000000001     10000000000001
```

Почему результат в столбцах `FL50,FL51` не был округлён? Что-то не понимаю в математике с плавающей точкой?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [numeric precision in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65662609) от участника [@ihadanny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574187/ihadanny)</sub>

Comment: ассоциция:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65662609

Answer (score 2):

В [документации также указано](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-10D4D073-866D-4BD4-B3E9-ED153D505A6A):

> The FLOAT data type is a subtype of NUMBER.

Таким образом, под капотом это `NUMBER`, и далее:

> To convert from binary to decimal precision, multiply n by 0.30103

Подставляем числа:

```
49 * 0.30103 = 14.75047
50 * 0.30103 = 15.05150
51 * 0.30103 = 15.65356
```

Таким образом, `FLOAT(50)` и `FLOAT(51)` соответствуют `NUMBER(16)`, тогда как `FLOAT(49)` является `NUMBER(15)`.

Это можно проверить, сделав дамп значений:

```
create table numeric_types2 (f1 float(60), n1 number)
/
insert into numeric_types2 
    with t as (
        select BIN_TO_NUM (
            1,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,1) n from dual
) select n, n from t;
    
select 'dump float' what, dump (f) dump from t union all 
select 'dump number',     dump (n)      from t union all 
select 'dump float50',    dump (cast (n as float(50))) from t union all
select 'dump float49',    dump (cast (n as float(49))) from t;

WHAT         DUMP                                            
------------ ------------------------------------------------
dump float   Typ=2 Len=9: 200,46,4,60,97,28,38,5,98          
dump number  Typ=2 Len=9: 200,46,4,60,97,28,38,5,98          
dump float50 Typ=2 Len=9: 200,46,4,60,97,28,38,5,98          
dump float49 Typ=2 Len=8: 200,46,4,60,97,28,38,6
```

Заметьте, что:

```
dump (f) = dump (n) = dump (cast (n as float(50)))
```

Только приведение числа к `float(49)` дает другое значение.

В заключение следует упомянуть, что документация содержит рекомендацию:

> Oracle Database uses the Oracle FLOAT data type internally when converting ANSI FLOAT data.   Oracle FLOAT is available for you to use, but Oracle recommends that you use the BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE data types instead, as they are more robust.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65669576) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>